# extract information separated with pipes from file and save it to another file

Tags: java

considering the following file "sample.txt" as input for a java program which contains the following information:

```
#1|77|1391436891|1|1|00:1e:58:f4:15:f7|Nexus 4, 4.4, MAKOZ30d
$1|1391436893
?[176.08179, -13.839829, -1.0054213]
%PKKV7|00:7f:28:3f:17:9d|-67|2437
%DC2VJ|f8:e4:fb:a0:06:f8|-71|2412
%VVWSP|00:7f:28:d5:92:65|-71|2462
%SVT8H|f8:e4:fb:8e:d6:9b|-77|2437
%ThreeBestFriends|20:10:7a:14:6a:f7|-66|2452
%2X4C8|00:7f:28:44:23:da|-75|2437
%STDGD|f8:e4:fb:70:86:f4|-82|2462
%DeathStar|00:7f:28:be:c8:94|-84|2412
%Freeinternet|00:1e:58:f4:15:f7|-59|2437
%QB657|00:26:62:b7:16:4b|-88|2462
%375F2|00:26:b8:3e:0a:14|-70|2412
%E1K38|00:26:62:cf:90:37|-81|2412
```

I'm trying to get an "output.txt" file as following:

```
00:7f:28:3f:17:9d|-67
f8:e4:fb:a0:06:f8|-71
00:7f:28:d5:92:65|-71
f8:e4:fb:8e:d6:9b|-77
20:10:7a:14:6a:f7|-66
00:7f:28:44:23:da|-75
f8:e4:fb:70:86:f4|-82
00:7f:28:be:c8:94|-84
00:1e:58:f4:15:f7|-59
00:26:62:b7:16:4b|-88
00:26:b8:3e:0a:14|-70
00:26:62:cf:90:37|-81
```

any recommendations on how to achieve this in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression will extract this:

```
\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}\W{1}-\d{2}
```

http://ideone.com/FwpV7z

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String testData = "#1|77|1391436891|1|1|00:1e:58:f4:15:f7|Nexus 4, 4.4, MAKOZ30d $1|1391436893 ?[176.08179, -13.839829, -1.0054213] %PKKV7|00:7f:28:3f:17:9d|-67|2437 %DC2VJ|f8:e4:fb:a0:06:f8|-71|2412 %VVWSP|00:7f:28:d5:92:65|-71|2462 %SVT8H|f8:e4:fb:8e:d6:9b|-77|2437 %ThreeBestFriends|20:10:7a:14:6a:f7|-66|2452 %2X4C8|00:7f:28:44:23:da|-75|2437 %STDGD|f8:e4:fb:70:86:f4|-82|2462 %DeathStar|00:7f:28:be:c8:94|-84|2412 %Freeinternet|00:1e:58:f4:15:f7|-59|2437 %QB657|00:26:62:b7:16:4b|-88|2462 %375F2|00:26:b8:3e:0a:14|-70|2412 %E1K38|00:26:62:cf:90:37|-81|2412";
        String regularExpression = "\\w{2}:\\w{2}:\\w{2}:\\w{2}:\\w{2}:\\w{2}\\W{1}-\\d{2}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testData);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }

    }
}
```

output:

```
00:7f:28:3f:17:9d|-67
f8:e4:fb:a0:06:f8|-71
00:7f:28:d5:92:65|-71
f8:e4:fb:8e:d6:9b|-77
20:10:7a:14:6a:f7|-66
00:7f:28:44:23:da|-75
f8:e4:fb:70:86:f4|-82
```

Comment: thank you it's working. is there a way to input and output a file?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the line as a String you can use split to split it up for the pipes.

Comment: which function do I have to use to split up the pipes?

Comment: yourstring.split("|")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good start (might be typo's since I did write it straight in here)

```
//Read all lines, one line at a time with a simple scanner: 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("sample.txt"));
while (sc.hasNextLine()){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    //If the line starts with a % do something, else ignore
    if (line.charAt(0) == '%'){
        int firstPipe = line.indexOf("|");
        int secondPipe = line.indexOf("|",firstPipe);

        //Now use String.substring() and perhaps a temporary StringBuffer storage followed by, for example, a FileWriter to create the output file
```